# Custom select appears above the navigation menu

Tags: html, css

I made some custom selections, but when I open the menu they appear above, how can I make this not happen?

I just want the menu above all.

The menu items finish with 'Login'.

The header (navigation menu) has the id 'nav'.

I tried to change the position of custom selects, but it made the display so bad, custom selects and input above each other so probabily is not the right way, but the menu is above the selects.

**Before opening the menu:**

[image: Before]

**After opening the menu:**

[image: After]

CSS:

```
#nav {
    z-index: 0;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    list-style-type: none;
    background-color: transparent;
}

#logo {
    z-index: 1;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-right: auto;
    background-color: transparent;
}

@media (max-width: 1150px){
    #nav {
            position:absolute;
            background: #24252A;
            top: 0;
            right: 0vw;
            height: 100vh;
            padding-top: 80px;
            display: none;
            align-items: initial;
            width: 60vw;
        }
    
        #nav li {
            display: block;
            padding-top: 20px;
            padding-left: 40px;
        }
}
    
    #customSelectCat option, #customSelectSotCat option {
        background:  #4d5061;
    }
    
    #customArrowCat, #customArrowSotCat {
        border-top-right-radius: 5px;
        border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        display: block;
        background: #3b3c47;
        height: 100%;
        width: 4rem;
        pointer-events: none;
    }
    
    #customSelectCat, #customSelectSotCat {
        position: relative;
        width: 320px;
    }
    
    #customSelectSotCat select {
        display: none;
    }
    
    #customArrowSotCat {
        display: none;
    }
    
    #customArrowCat::after, #customArrowCat::before, #customArrowSotCat::after, #customArrowSotCat::before {
        --size: 0.5em;
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        width: 0;
        height: 0;
        left: 50%;
        top: 50%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    }
    
    #customArrowCat::before, #customArrowSotCat::before{
        border-left: var(--size) solid transparent;
        border-right: var(--size) solid transparent;
        border-bottom: var(--size) solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 255);
        top: 36%;
    }
    
    #customArrowCat::after, #customArrowSotCat::after {
        border-left: var(--size) solid transparent;
        border-right: var(--size) solid transparent;
        border-top: var(--size) solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 255);
        top: 64%;
    }
```

HTML:

```
<div id="searchBar">
                    <h2> Ricerca degli eventi </h2>
                    <div id="flexSearch">
                        <div id="customSelectCat">
                            <?php
                                if(isset($_SESSION['option'])){
                                    echo $_SESSION['option'];
                                    unset($_SESSION['option']);
                                } else {
                            ?>
                                    <select id="listCat">
                                        <option value="" disabled selected hidden>Seleziona la categoria</option>
                                        <option value="Concerti">Concerti</option>
                                        <option value="Sport">Sport</option>
                                        <option value="MostreEMusei">Mostre e Musei</option>
                                        <option value="Teatro">Teatro</option>
                                    </select>
                            <?php
                                }
                            ?>
                            <span id="customArrowCat"></span>
                        </div>
                        <div id="customSelectSotCat">
                            <select id="listSotCat">
                            </select>
                            <span id="customArrowSotCat"></span>
                        </div>
                        <input type="date" id="dateFrom" name="dateFrom" onkeydown="return false">
                        <input type="date" id="dateTo" name="dateTo" onkeydown="return false">
                        <button id="cerca">Cerca</button><br>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

**Thank you!**

Comment: set z-index of navbar to 999

Comment: This is not the right way, because navbar has z-index 0 because has to stay below logo. I have modified my CSS with other code.

Comment: u can also use z-index for your logo to be higher than navbar, anyway it isgreat that you have fixed it good luck,

Comment: @BurhamB.Soliman no, i didn't fixed it unfortunately.

Comment: then go as i told you it will be fixed =)